Problem when requiring packages bundled with webpack
I'm able to use libraries with node like:
const API = require("api");
const Service = require("service");

however, when I bundle the js file with webpack, it doesn't work and I need to change the way I require them to:
const { API } = require("api");
const Service = require("service").default;

This is my webpack.config.js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./libs.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "out"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    library: "bundle",
    libraryTarget: "var",
  },
};

Is this expected or am I missing something?
thanks!

Your current configuration with libraryTarget: 'var' exposes the return value of your entry point as:
exports.default = /* return value of entry point */

Set your libraryTarget to 'commonjs' to have the return value of your entry point will be assigned to the exports object and not the default variable.
module.exports = /* return value of entry point */

When a module has the desired export object assigned to module.exports, you can require it directly.
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./libs.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "out"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    library: "bundle",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs",
  },
};

